# Python Qt and multi row qlabel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, styles

I want to have the results of an rss feed in the same qlabel.  Here is my label

```
Title = QLabel("Title: %s " % (title.text), self)
desc = QLabel("Summary: %s " % (desc.text), self)
```

And here is my layout Currently

```
    h_splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
    h_splitter1.addWidget(Title)
    h_splitter1.addWidget(Desc)
```

As of right now that shows in seperate splitter boxes.  How can i combine them so that they show like this:

```
Title: Price, Sox look forward to re-setting Tuesday
Desc: Red Sox ace David Price had no issue with Monday's "coldout" in Cleveland. Roughly an hour after the decision had been made to postpone Opening Day until Tuesday at 1:10 p.m. ET, Price still had numbness in his throwing hand -- and that was just from playing catch for five minutes.
```

Also a second problem is how can i get Desc to wrap within the splitter box?  Say at x amoutn of characters go to new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
desc = QLabel("Title: %s\nSummary: %s " % (title.text, desc.text), self)
```

Comment: Great thank you.  I was missing the "\nSummary" when i read the docs.  Easy miss. Thanks again.

Comment: you wouldnt also know how i would go about getting it to wrap inside the box would you?  Say i want it to break at 50 characters?